# SetFocus not setting focus to inputfield

Tags: android, android-studio, focus

I have a scannfunctionality on my app.
I have an inputfield to scan with a barcodescanner(external keyboard). After a successful scan, the focus should return to this input field.

In Fragment:

```
 EditText handscann=rootView.findViewById(R.id.handscannerinput);
 handscann.requestFocus();
```

In xml:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/handscannerinput"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@{vmScann.handscannerArticlenumber}"
    android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme">
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

my problem is, the focus is not set to this inputfield, but to a switcher which is on the same view.

when I touch the switcher, the focus goes to the inputfield.
The switcher has a other id:

```
 <Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:checked="@={vmScann.myArticleSwitchActivated}"
    android:theme="@style/SwitchThemeGreen"
    android:paddingRight="15dp" />
```

does anyone have an idea why this is so?

Edit:
I check after request focus which view has the focus with

```
View view=rootView.findFocus();
```

this say the focus is on handscannerinput...

after that I check with hasfocus() but this are false

```
if(handscann.hasFocus()){
    int i=0; //for the breakpoint
}
```

Comment: You state that you want the focus to go the `EditText` after scanning. So have you set `EditText#requestFocus();` on a call back which notify the finish of scan?

Comment: Yes, when a scan is done, a method is called in the fragment to set focus. In this method is the 2 lines (findbyid and request)

Comment: use edittext.requestFocus() to set focus to edit text

Answer (score 0):

Intialise and cast `handscann` in `onViewCreated()` or `onCreateView()` function of Fragment
Add `requestFocus()` after Succesfull Scan function

ie onFinsih of Scan call `requestFocus()` inside the Callback Function

```
your callBackFunction(){ 

    //Do Opertions
    yourSwitch.clearFocus();
    handscann.setText(text); //If any
    handscann.requestFocus();
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    handscann.requestFocus();
}
```

Comment: @Andreas I had Updated the Answer. Check that. You have to instialise and Cast the Edittext and Switch Outside the Function in onViewCreated or in onCreateView

Comment: ahh, i see. i'm was to fast with my comment.. now i have the findbyid in the onCreateView. but still does the same (wrong)

Comment: where did you intialised or Casted your Switch

Comment: use `yourSwitch.clearFocus();` before adding requestFous for the Text

Comment: i have tryed with clearFocus but has no effect.
Normality i using the databind concept. first i create a binding and set the model. after this i make View rootview= bindingname.getRoot(). after this i make the findbyid for the inputfield and now also for the switcher. for the functionality: i give a productnumber into the inputfield when i press enter, it call a method add to basket. is this complete i have a callback to the fragment where I want to set the focus new

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161599/discussion-between-tomin-b-and-andreas).

Comment: Add onResume() inisdeFragment

Comment: this has also no effect. 
what I find very strange is that the switcher gets the focus, if I press the switcher, then the focus goes to the input field...

Comment: I testet after clearFocus() on the switcher and requestFocus() on the edittext with 2 if statements to check both hasFocus(). on debug both are true..